# How do I make my Unity3d camera rotate around his following object?

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

I'm making a game but I do not now how to let my camera rotate with the object he's following. (I did the follow part) Can somebody help me please. I'm using C#.

Comment: This may help you out http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/600577/camera-rotation-around-player-while-following.html Also you may want to provide some code for people to help you, with just a sentence you aren't going to be welcomed by many people

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `transform.RotateAround` to move the camera. This should be done inside the update method in your camera.

For example:

```
var target:transform;

function Update(){
     //...
     transform.RotateAround (target.position, Vector3.up, speed * Time.deltaTime);
}
```

For more information on the rotation method, see the [docs](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.RotateAround.html).

Answer (score 1):

Please, can you describe what you actually want to do? What does "let my camera rotate with the object" mean?

If you want your camera to exactly follow the gameobject's rotation in a first person camera, you could achieve this by putting your camera as the gameobject's child.
You could also do this using the following code:

```
[SerializeField]
private Transform obj; //reference the gameobject's transform

void Update()
{
    transform.rotation = obj.rotation;
}
```

Comment: I'm making a game for my school, it's a game with Pokémon ish controls like walkig diagonal and horizontal. The camera has to turn when I go to the left. You know so I can make you can see the left and right side of my Pixelart player model.

Comment: I'm still not sure about what you want to do. It seems like a third person view from what I understand. You could add a gameObject on your player that will be the center of rotation of your camera. Then put the camera as a child of this object and move it as you want. You can then turn the center of rotation so that your camera rotates around the player as you want.

Comment: @MandiRex, if you could clarify exactly what you want, that would be great. If you could share parts of your code, that would be even better.

Answer (score 1):

If you want simple 3rd person camera, you can place camera as a child of your target object - the camera will "stick to it.

**If you want to do this in code (for some reasons)**, something like this should work (attach script to GameObject with Camera component):

```
using UnityEngine;

public class CameraFollow : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform target; // Object to fallow. Select in Inspector
    public Vector3 offset = new Vector3(0, 0, -10); // Offset to target

    private GameObject container; // Container for our camera

    void Start()
    {
        container = new GameObject("Camera Container"); // Create container (empty GameObject) for camera to avoid unnecessary calculations. It will follow the target object
        transform.parent = container.transform; // Make this object child of container
    }

    //Update your camera follow script in LateUpade(), to be sure that 'target' movement is done
    void LateUpdate()
    {
        //Check if target is selected
        if (target == null)
            return;

        container.transform.position = target.position; // Set container position same as target 
        container.transform.rotation = target.rotation; // Set container rotation same as target 

        transform.localPosition = offset; // Move camera by offset inside the container
        transform.LookAt(target); // Optionaly, force camera look at target object on any offset
    }
}
```